# Cannot send the mail with attachment in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the dropdown list with fields Lab,Pharmacy,Food and Nurse.When I select the lab it generates the new fields and when I select the pharmacy it generates the new field with upload button.I need to send the mail with these details for lab and pharmacy.

By using below mail function I can send only for lab but when I select pharmacy I could not send any mail.Please help me

form.phtml

```
    <form action="http://www.labwise.in/devel/serviceform/submit" id="quickservice" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li>
        <label for="Servicetype" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Service Type') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select id='servicetype'   onchange="showHidden(this)" name="servicetype" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 200px;" />
                        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
                        <option value="Lab" id='lab'><?php echo $this->__('Lab')?></option>
                        <option value="Pharmacy"><?php echo $this->__('Pharmacy')?></option>
                        <option value="Food"><?php echo $this->__('Food')?></option>
                        <option value="Gym"><?php echo $this->__('Gym')?></option>
                        <option value="Physio"><?php echo $this->__('Physio')?></option>
                        <option value="Nurse"><?php echo $this->__('Nurse')?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fileToUpload" style='display: none;'>

        <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="medicinename" ><?php echo $this->__('Medicine Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="medicinename" name="medicinename" value="" class="input-text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Medicine Name') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
                    <p>(upload your prescription )</p>
        <div class="fields">
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="pname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
                <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="pcity" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="pcity" name="pcity" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">

                <label for="zip_code" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="zip_code" id="zip_code" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip Code') ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                </div>

        </li>

        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="city_name" style='display: none;'>
        <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="testname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Testname') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Testname') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
                <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="rcity" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="rcity" name="rcity" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">

                <label for="zip_code" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="zip_code" id="zip_code" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip Code') ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                </div>

        </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="food" style='display: none;'>
    <ul class="form-list">

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="fname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>

        <li class="fields">
            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
                <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">
            <label for="fcity" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="fcity" name="fcity" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>"/>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="fields">

                <label for="zip_code" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="zip_code" id="zip_code" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip Code') ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                </div>

        </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>


    <div class="button">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

if(Validation) {
    Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
    function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

    var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
    // var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
    if(v.length > 0){
    if(v.length !=10){
        return false;
       }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

        return false;
       }


    return true;

    }else {
    return false;
    }

    }
    ]])};

        var contactForm = new VarienForm('quickservice', true);
      //]]>
     </script>

    <script>
    function showHidden(elem){
       if(elem.value == 'Pharmacy')
       {
          document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('food').style.display = "none";
         // document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "none";
         // document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "none";
          //document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(elem.value == 'Lab')
       {
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('food').style.display = "none";
         // document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "none";
         // document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "none";
         // document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(elem.value == 'Food')
       {
          document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('food').style.display = "block";
         // document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "none";
         //  document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "none";
         // document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(elem.value == 'Gym')
       {
           document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('food').style.display = "block";
          //document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "block";
        //  document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "none";
         /// document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(elem.value == 'Physio')
       {
           document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('food').style.display = "block";
          // document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "none";
          // document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "block";
          // document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(elem.value == 'Nurse')
       {
           document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('food').style.display = "block";
           //document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "none";
          // document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "none";
          // document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "block";
       }
       else
       {
           document.getElementById('fileToUpload').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('city_name').style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById('food').style.display = "none";
           //document.getElementById('gym').style.display = "none";
          // document.getElementById('physio').style.display = "none";
           //document.getElementById('nurse').style.display = "none";
       }
    }
    </script>
```

mail.phtml

```
 <?php
//Admin Mail
      function sendMailAction(){
       //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
     $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
      $testname=$_POST['testname'];
     $name=$_POST['name'];
     $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $city=$_POST['rcity'];


   $html=
 ' <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
    <p>Testname:'.$testname.' </p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
      <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
      <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     <p>City: '.$city.'</p>'


     ;
     $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
     $mail->setToName('admin');
    $mail->setToEmail($email);
   $mail->setBody($html);
    $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
    $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
      $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
  //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
   $mail->send();
     //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
    //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
    //return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
    //$this->_redirect('');
     }
    catch (Exception $e) {
   //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
    //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
    //$this->_redirect('');
         }
         }
      //Customer Mail

         function sendMailcustomerAction(){
         //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
          $email=$_POST['email'];
           $testname=$_POST['testname'];
           $name=$_POST['name'];
           $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
            $city=$POST_['city'];

             $html=
            'Dear '.$name.',

               <p>We have received your order for '.$testname.'. You will be attended shortly.</p>

              <p>Best Regards,</p>
               <p>Team Labwise.</p>'

       ;
        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName($name);
        $mail->setToEmail($email);
           $mail->setBody($html);
        $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
         $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
        $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
        //$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
        $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
    $mail->send();
       //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
         return '<h2>Your Request has been submitted.Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
        //$this->_redirect('');
        }
       catch (Exception $e) {
      //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
    //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
     return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';
    //$this->_redirect('');
       }
        }

  //pharmacy

   $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
   $query="SELECT *
 FROM mg_serviceprovider  where islab='1' or ispharmacy='1'";
  $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($query);

 foreach($alldata as $data)
   {
     if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy') { 
         sendMailpharmacyandlabAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
  } else {
  sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
  }
  }
 function sendMailpharmacyandlabAction($cemail,$pname){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
 $cemail=$_POST['email'];

       if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and $servicetype=='Pharmacy')
       {

        $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
        $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

          $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
          $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
          $target_path_upl =  Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
    if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
        @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
    }
    }

   $html=
  '<p>Hi,</p>'

    ;

       $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName($pname);
      $mail->setToEmail($cemail);
    $mail->setBody($html);
    $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
   $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
    $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
       if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
      {
      $mail->createAttachment(
          file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename),
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        basename($uploadfilename)
    );
    }
    //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
     $mail->send();


  unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename); 
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
     //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
   return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
     //$this->_redirect('');
    }
  catch (Exception $e) {
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
  //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
 //$this->_redirect('');
   }
   }
  echo sendMailpharmacyandlabAction();
  echo sendMailserviceAction();
  echo sendMailcustomerAction();
  echo sendMailAction();

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method createAttachment in Mage_Core_Model_Email. Try to use Zend_Mail instead.
As addition, my advice is to refactor your code following Magento extension standard. Most of your php code should be put to controller and block; you need to add screening while using variables from $_POST array to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you please suggest me.How to put to controller and block